# Xampp mysql server suddenly not starting

Tags: mysql, xampp

I used Xampp a few hours ago wanted to start mysqlserver again but it gave me a error message that mysql shut down unexpectedly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JblcH.png)

And yes the port is not used checked it with netstat -an | findstr "3306" command
and even tried to change the port to 3307 but neither that worked

And the error logs show no error:

```
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\Xampp\Xampphpupgrade\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\Xampp\Xampphpupgrade\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 7528999; transaction id 39501
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\Xampp\Xampphpupgrade\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-10-13 19:58:12 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: perhaps reinstall the latest version?

Comment: Not sure could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MySql is new without important databases, you can try these steps:

1. Shut down your Xampp server
2. Go to C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3. delete the **ibdata1** file
4. Restart your Xampp server

Deleting ibdata1 file may destroy your tables, backup everything.