# XAMPP MySQL cannot start

Tags: mysql, xampp

Xampp mysql phpmyadmin was running perfectly a few days ago. But now it's has this problem.
I have tried stop the mysql in service.msc, i have tried to chang the port. I have tried to run XAMPP as administrator. But it's still not work.
Could if because of a django project i've just installed? if that so, how do i fix it?

---

Update:  this is the error in file .log . Sorry, this is my first time I use stackoverflow and my English is not really good so i still find some struggle.

```
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=52] log sequence number 3793714 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=316] log sequence number 3793714 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=295] log sequence number 3797169 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=418] log sequence number 3797169 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=296] log sequence number 3541481 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=419] log sequence number 3541481 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=438] log sequence number 3120739 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 898895.
2021-10-31  0:21:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
```

[XAMPP control panel. Mysql cannot start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8la1.png)

Comment: Hi @Dr.Doof11, XAMPP is telling you to check the logs, in order to obtain more information about the problem. Have you tried that? 
Once you find the log, you can share the error message here. Without this info, is hard to help you.
Tip: post the log error as text, not as a screenshot, it will help other people in the future to find the solution.

Comment: check your firewall.If you on ubuntu or other linux distro with ufw installed you could do `ufw allow <port number>`. But, because you on windows, allow the ports in firewall and make sure the ports haven't been used by other processes.

Comment: @funder7 Thank you for remind me. I have uploaded the logs. Is there anythings else i need to do?

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho Can you tell me more about how to do it? I think i found that port 3306 in "Window Defender Firewall with Advance Security" but don't know what to do next

Comment: Maybe this [article](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html) will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly I found this solution and it's work!!! Also thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch yes haha that exactly what i need

Comment: Sorry about that @Dr.Doof11, when we flag a question as a duplicate, StackOverflow automatically posts that comment, which looks really silly when I’m telling you what you already know!

Comment: @IsaacBennetch so my english is bad and this is the first time i use stackoverflow, so i don't understand what are you sorry me about. But it's ok though haha

Comment: @Dr.Doof11 writing good questions on SF is good for who is reading (and in consequence, who can help you), but also to find existing answers. When you create a new question, SF provides you a list of similar posts. That's why the title is fundamental!
This article contains plenty of information about how to ask questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... Welcome on board. :)