# Stored Procedures backup on "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, xampp

I have opened XAMPP to start working and I have gotten the error that states

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

I fixed everything following the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

But after I started interacting with APIs I am developing I found that my backend was having issues those issues every single call I made:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE
> DB.PROCEDURE_NAME does not exist

Further investigation showed that, while I made a completely working backup for my tables and my data, there is no backup for my stored procedures and I pretty much lost everything I had.

So now the question comes by itself:
**How to backup the stored procedures the same way as the table, once the XAMPP MySQL Error prompts out?**

Comment: How was the `backup for my tables and data` done, with `mysqldump`? If so, what does the command look like? ... If you have the old `information_schema`, you may be able to get the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` from the `ROUTINES` table to save some work.

Comment: Backup was made with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly#answer-61859561, as I stated in the question. I have no idea how to backup with mysqldump

Comment: Though you do not mention anything about `mysqldump` in your question, that was an inquiry of my own, as to what you do for backups. So, based on your claim to: `I made a completely working backup for my tables and my data`, then what exactly is your backup handling? [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) is a MySQL utility to help facilitate DB backups, which would include `routines` if applied properly.

Comment: When XAMPP fails to load MySQL, I follow the steps to recreate a working folder with tables and data, from the question I shared with you above. There is no backup handling. I know this method work because I have already used for many times as XAMPP crashes often. So I have no clue on how to use mysqldump (I am reading the link you sent now)