# MySQL (MariaDB) Won't Start on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, mariadb

I facing an issue, very regularly that i wanna write it about.

ENVIRONMENT:
OS: Windows 11
TOOLS: XAMPP v3.3.0 (Apr 6 2021)

PROBLEM:
I am using xampp, with mariadb inside.
Mariadb wont start, after i restart my computer.
This behavior is not always but often.
That makes me uneasy to put it on from laptop to a real server.

my.ini:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# D:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = ABC
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
#ASW
default-character-set=utf8mb4


# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
#innodb_force_recovery = 0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M 
max_connections=99999
max_user_connections=99999

#ASW
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
#ASW
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
#ASW
character-set-server = utf8mb4
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="D:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="D:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1"
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=510m
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=1
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
#ASW
innodb_fast_shutdown=0

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

mysql_error.log:

```
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'innodb_buffer_pool_instance' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'innodb-buffer-pool-instances' instead.
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-04-13  7:15:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 952280386; transaction id 29943
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220413  7:16:01
2022-04-13  7:16:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Windows Event Viewer:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MariaDB" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">100</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-04-13T04:32:36.9001104Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4354354</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="13772" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>LAPTOP-6SGBQVBS</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MariaDB" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">100</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-04-13T04:32:36.9001104Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4354353</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="13772" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>LAPTOP-6SGBQVBS</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>InnoDB: Page [page id: space=1085, page number=2] log sequence number 951251554 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2229643.</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I have searched for an answer to solve the issue; here is how i am recovering my databases: repair-mysql-data.ps1:

```
# Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/1956278
$loc = "D:\xampp\mysql"
$dataOld = "./data_old_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)"
$dataOld_ibdata1 = $( $dataOld + "/ibdata1" )
$backup = "./backup"
$target = "./data"
$target_ibdata1 = $( $target + "/ibdata1" )
$targetTest = "./data/test"

Write-Output $( "Will go to dir " + $loc )
pause
Set-Location -Path $loc

Write-Output $( "Will rename data to " + $dataOld )
pause
Rename-Item -Path $target -NewName $dataOld

Write-Output $( "Will copy data from " + $backup + " to " +  $target )
pause
Copy-Item -Path $backup -Destination $target -Recurse

Write-Output $( "Will delete directory " + $targetTest )
pause
Remove-Item $targetTest -Recurse

Write-Output $( "Will restore databases except mysql,performance_schema,phpmyadmin from " + $dataOld + " to " + $target )
pause
$dbPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $dataOld -Exclude ('mysql', 'performance_schema', 'phpmyadmin') -Recurse -Directory
Copy-Item -Path $dbPaths.FullName -Destination $target -Recurse

Write-Output $( "Will restore ibdata1 from " + $dataOld_ibdata1 + " to " + $target_ibdata1 )
pause
Copy-Item -Path $dataOld_ibdata1 -Destination $target_ibdata1 
Write-Output $( "Previous data is located at " + $dataOld )

Write-Output $( "Start Mysql Now!" )
pause
Write-Output $( "goto http://localhost/phpmyadmin and press log-out once..." )
$url = "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/logout"
PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET 

pause
```

I want to try the solution in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/.
Could you elaborate on:

- Where and what one should put it in my.ini file
- What is your experiences, on solving the issue?

Accordiong to @Akina 's comment, I copied and edited "D:\xampp\mysql_start.bat" file as below and tried values from 1 to 4.

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
echo Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
echo Please dont close Window while MySQL is running
echo MySQL is trying to start
echo Please wait  ...
echo MySQL is starting with mysql\bin\my.ini (console)

mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --innodb_force_recovery=1

if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo MySQL konnte nicht gestartet werden
echo MySQL could not be started
pause

:finish
```

Recovery results are negative...
bat file results:

```
Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
Please dont close Window while MySQL is running
MySQL is trying to start
Please wait  ...
MySQL is starting with mysql\bin\my.ini (console)
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld (mysqld 10.4.24-MariaDB) starting as process 15564 ...

MySQL konnte nicht gestartet werden
MySQL could not be started
Press any key to continue . . .
```

mysql_error.log:

```
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 2 !!!
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 955000055; transaction id 13812
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2022-04-15  5:08:15 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 2 !!!
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 955000064; transaction id 13812
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2022-04-15  5:08:32 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Event Viewer:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="MariaDB" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">100</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-04-15T02:08:32.9255762Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4479194</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="15564" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>LAPTOP-6SGBQVBS</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: *Where and what one should put it in my.ini file* Put `--innodb_force_recovery=N` to the service command line, and remove it after recovering completed.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. Next time it occurs, i will the put recovery command inside D:\xampp\mysql_start.bat file, and check the results.

Comment: *i will the put recovery command inside D:\xampp\mysql_start.bat file* Does this batch starts MariaDB service process directly? or it uses some system call (for example, some SC START)? if last then I doubt that specified command line setting will be transferred correctly...

Comment: @Akina I will directly doubleclick the file; so i guess process directly. I copied "D:\xampp\mysql_start.bat" file as mysql_start_width_fix_1.bat. Then I changed line 9 as "mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --innodb_force_recovery=1". I wish it will work, when the next crash happens. I will report here the result.

Comment: @Akina I tried it but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by writting a daily automatic backup code for every databases.

Hence, when the problem happens,

- I am just deleting the folder D:\xampp\mysql\data
- And copying D:\xampp\mysql\backup as D:\xampp\mysql\data.
- And double clicking the database restore-bat-file that automatically created.

Here is the daily backup implementation i am using: [github](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.sql.backup)

- BACKUP: creating a dump file for every databases. And adding table creating sql on the top.
- COMPRESS: Compressing the dump file, deleting the old dump file
- RESTORE: And pairing every dump file with a restore-bat-file.