# XAMPP - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly / Blocked Port

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 Community . After that Xampp gives blocked port error.

Then I uninstall VS22 but still the same.

Error:

```
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 445?
180718 12:43:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I checked connections and I don't know if it matters but doesn't have 3306 port.

[image]

I've tried to change ports in config files but still doesn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says you might already have a server running on port `445`.

On your terminal, try shutting down all `xammp` server then restart `xammp`.

`C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqladmin" −u root shutdown`

Answer (score 1):

Instead, first try using the MySQL backup folder which is included with XAMPP. So do next steps:

1. Rename folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old
2. Make a copy of mysql/backup folder and name it as mysql/data
3. Copy all your database folders from mysql/data_old into mysql/data (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders)
4. Copy mysql/data_old/ibdata1 file into mysql/data folder
5. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

Comment: This seems to have been plagiarised from [Rasul Ebrahimzadeh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-can-i-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/65047764#65047764) (to another question). Or there is a common source it has been plagiarised from.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Homestad. It is lot easier to use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re *"Homestad"*: Do you mean *"[Homestead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features)"*?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Services* and stop MySQL80. It worked to me.