# MYSQL WONT OPEN XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Trying to run MYSQL in XAMPP. I get an error message. Below is the error log. tried replacing mysql folder in xammp with a new one didnt fix it. pls help?

```
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:22:50 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the
```

Comment: Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling your wifi, if it is, then check your wifi certificates.

If this does not work, manually uninstall XAMPP and then reinstall it.

Comment: will this not delete my files saved in xampp?

Comment: Did you check if the port 3306 is not used at all?

Comment: yes and it isn't!