# ERROR: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I already tried all the solutions and answers from here  [How to solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)
but I'm still receiving this error. Anyone can help me ??
Last week I can still use all my xampp but when I turned on my Laptop I'm receiving  this errors.

```
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-06-13  9:13:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 15457105; transaction id 22547
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-06-13  9:14:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Update: I just keep my starting the MySQL and it starts but the problem when I try to access  localhost/phpmyadmin i have this error 

This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Update 2: I also notice my Apache Port it keeps changing to other ports instead of 80,443

Answer (score 0):

try to go to this path

```
C:\xampp\mysql\data
```

and cut all files ( except folders and files in green cover ,leave all folders as it is )

cut all files in red cover and paste on new folder in desktop

then stop appache and mysql then start again [image]

if this fails try this method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526334/10436478