# XAMPP MySQL Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly with tried solutions

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried all the solutions online but I'm still having error with xampp mysql someone can help me??
Here's one of the solution I tried based on votes [How to solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Here's my error log:

```
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 47133; transaction id 8
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220930 17:14:33
2022-09-30 17:14:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: Nope, still facing same error

Comment: If that is where your log ends then I would suspect the **ib_buffer_pool** file.  Make sure mysql is not running (check Task Manager) and rename this file.  See if this works.

Comment: @RohitGupta still the same 
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 47205; transaction id 8
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2022-10-03 10:31:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.