# Base table or view not found: 1932 Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I had a problem with laravel. I was doing a project to make a book management app, so i went out to take a short break and come back to it. When i tried to run the project again it gave me an error[saying "Base table or view not found: 1932 Table doesn't exist"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBpiS.png)

Also there's seems to be a problem with my phpmyadmin database which shows collation in use [phpmyadmin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhLL7.png)

I have search it up, and found that i can fix my probelm by running`php artisan config:cache` but there's another problem where everytime i run php artisan command, the same error shows up. [error running php artisan migrate:fresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApQ7R.png).
[error running php artisan config:cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KTpb.png)

Comment: How did you solve your phpmyadmin problem? You probably deleted your database in process

Comment: @AdemirŠehić i tried to use different database where it no longer shows collation in use. but now i still can't run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: have you checked the database? if this table name exists or not. Or you can check xampp if the MySQL connection working or not. usually, this error occurs if PHPMyAdmin stops working.

Comment: @M.Haris myphpadmin shows me this error Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
after i search it up, i found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly
i don't know if it probably contribute to the error or not. Yes the database is there and i can even open it up  after i tried the solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhLL7.png

Comment: You did not copy old ibdata1 file