# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly due to a blocked port,

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using Xampp

When I am starting the MySQL I am getting the below error

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
1.45.27 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

When this error arrived at first I have tried to restart MySQL from services manually and it was working fine but after some days it again shows the same error

I tried to change the data folder and copying the files from backup folder

[How to solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

I have also tried to reinstall the xampp by uninstalling it still I am getting the same error.

Comment: What about the machine specs? Do they meet the minimum cpu and ram requested by mysql?