# XAMPP MariaDB crashed during editing Elementor page and now won't restart

Tags: mariadb, xampp

I was editing a Elementor Wordpress page and the MariaDB server crashed. This is the second time this has happened. I can't restart the MariaDB server and I believe it is a corrupted table but I can't login to the MariaDB shell because the server won't start in the first place. I have included the logs below.

Here are the errors from the XAMPP Control Panel:

```
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, <br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this<br>
4:34:27 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Here are the errors from the shell

```
# mysql --user=root --password=
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

```
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=178429380
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 178429389; transaction id 69148
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-13  8:31:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 24412
    Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5c4d)
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=190793810
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-14 16:18:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 190793819; transaction id 72479
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2023-11-14 16:18:29 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2023-11-14 16:30:55 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 26036
    Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5c4d)
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 190793828; transaction id 72479
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2023-11-14 16:30:56 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 13804
    Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5c4d)
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 190793837; transaction id 72479
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2023-11-14 16:32:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 31052
    Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5c4d)
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\rc_2024_cd101\wp14rc_options.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_options``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_options` because it could not be opened.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\rc_2024_cd101\wp14rc_postmeta.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_postmeta``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_postmeta` because it could not be opened.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\rc_2024_cd101\wp14rc_posts.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_posts``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_posts` because it could not be opened.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\rc_2024_cd101\wp14rc_postmeta.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_postmeta``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\rc_2024_cd101\wp14rc_options.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-11-14 16:34:25 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``rc_2024_cd101`.`wp14rc_options``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 190793846; transaction id 72479
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2023-11-14 16:34:25 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions "Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files"

```
F:
cd F:\Code\XAMPP\mysql\data\
.\bin\aria_chk -f -f -r *\*.MAI
```

if that is successful:

```
del aria_log.*
```

InnoDB readonly files is odd. Did some permission change on the files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a post that fixed the problem. It turns out it wasn't a problem with tables it was actually a XAMPP related problem.

[This stack overflow allowed me to recover my databases:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-can-i-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly?rq=2)

Additionally, I found another stack overflow that suggested installing an earlier version of XAMPP.

Comment: There is nothing in common with the other question apparat from both are using XAMPP and failed to start.  Error messages are placed in the log file for reading and basic comparison. Not all "fail to start" are the same.