# MariaDB always displays message Erorr:MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mariadb, xampp, shutdown

I have a database called sik. to display the phpmyadmin page is very good, and opening another database is no problem, but there is one database called sik in my database, when it is displayed

My XAMPP displays an error message **MySQL shutdown unexpectedly**.
[image]

Only 1 table cannot be displayed

I have tried several ways to solve this problem but still can't

can anyone help me solve this

logs eror :

```
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``tesdatabase`.`zis_keterangan_lantai_rumah_penerima_dankes``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `tesdatabase`.`zis_keterangan_lantai_rumah_penerima_dankes` because it could not be opened.
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.

2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xamppkz\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xamppkz\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 300333; transaction id 104659
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xamppkz\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2023-11-22 19:55:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Follow the directions on that error panel. View the logs. If you need help interpreting them [edit] your question to show us some log entries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-can-i-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

Comment: The table is damaged. Please contact me if you need to deal with it.

Comment: I've edited it and included the error logs

Comment: Check the file permissions on the tablespace file named in the log (`<datadir>/tesdatabase.zis_keterangan_lantai_rumah_penerima_dankes`). Is it readable and writable by the MariaDB Server process?

Comment: According to your log, you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. We should all start thinking of MariaDB as a distinct product from MySQL, because solutions for MariaDB are not necessarily the same solutions for MySQL. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and both have changed enough since then that they now have many incompatibilities. I've edited your title and tags to clarify you are using MariaDB.

Comment: Can you explain the solution clearly and in detail, sorry, I'm a beginner.
actually there are still a lot of error logs, but I only show some of them, but strangely it's only sik database that has problems, the others don't

Comment: [Operating system error 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) is "ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, 3 (0x3), The system cannot find the path specified." What files are in "C:\xamppkz\mysql\data\"?