XAMPP - phpmyadmin will not start any more / MYSQL issue
Please don't notice red messages in pictures. They are not important for specific picture (it's the message of the issue before)
If I try starting XAMPP Apache and MySQL, MySQL will not start under Windows10. After having deleted aria_log.00000X file in folder C:\xampp\mysql\data MySql will run like this:

Now, if I try start running phpmyadmin pushing Admin Button left of MySQL, I notice changing Apache ports from 80/443 towards 53703. Also PID is changing:

phpmyAdmin will not run in Browser. Stopping MySQL Server and restarting it again will fail now, generally

How to fix this issue?
I tried to start phpmyadmin using this fix: https://julianlang.net/xampp-mysql-startet-nicht-mehr/

check the reference link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-can-i-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly
This will solve your problem
