# Cannot start mysql in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql

Xampp mysql phpmyadmin was running perfectly a few days ago. Now I am encountering this problem.

I tried changing port numbers but I still encounter this problem

A windows error prompts telling me that:

mysqld.exe has stopped working with the following problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: mysqld.exe
  Application Version:  5.6.16.0
  Application Timestamp:    52d55dcc
  Fault Module Name:    mysqld.exe
  Fault Module Version: 5.6.16.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   52d55dcc
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00b5957a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Xampp Control Panel also provided with the following error details:

```
10:47:55 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
10:47:56 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:47:56 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:47:59 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I also tried doing this which was effective for some people with the same problem

[XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

I opened the error logs but I can't seem to understand what it says.

```
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-08-27 09:12:23 ce4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625987 and 1625987 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3459249 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 3459249
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-08-27 09:12:25 3296 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-08-27 09:12:26 3296 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-08-27 09:12:26 3296 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.16'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I also encountered a solution for this which is changing the port again that conflicts with skype. But I don't have skype installed in my PC

[XAMPP - Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

I also tried NetStat to check if my default mysql port 3306 is being used, but it mentioned that no services were using that port.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

When my error not run in mysql
InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages

solution : delete ibdata1, all (ib_logfile)... and restart xampp

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your own linked SO page has the answer. From your error log:

> 2014-08-27 09:12:23 3296 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625987 and 1625987 in ***ibdata*** files do not match the log sequence number 3459249 in the ib_logfiles!

Then, from the highest rated answer in [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly)

> - exit Xampp server
> - go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
> - ***delete the ibdata1 file***
> - restart xampp server

Try that and you should have it beat.

Comment: I already deleted the ibdata1 file. Still encountering the same error :(

Comment: Then I would try shutting down mysql, adding `innodb_force_recovery = 1` within [mysqld] section in your mysql configuration, then restart=ing mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But still same error shows on my control panel :(

Comment: @Borsalino have you found a solution to this problem? i'm having the same problem..

Comment: Same problem for me also

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. unfortunately, above solutions didn't worked for me.
I have solved it by deleting ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1... all log files and my xampp is working fine now!
According to above solutions if I delete ibdata1 file then my all databases got lost.
So, I keep ibdata1 file and deleted all log files.

Thanks to the stackoverflow.com