# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have trouble running mysql using xampp on a win10 machine.
Here is the xampp message:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
1:33:01  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:33:01  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:33:01  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:33:01  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:33:01  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:33:01  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

And this is my mysql.log:

```
017-10-18 03:52:49 efc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-10-18  3:52:49 3836 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have tried reinitilizing mysql data folder, deleting ibdata1, ib_log files from it, without any success.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port as specified on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly by rinuthomaz

Comment: Anyone answer for this ?, have same issue, clearing `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`,  `ib_log` and `ibdata1` getting success at first time , after restart getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by Install 5.6.35 / PHP 5.6.35 - XAMPP

Have same issue by using windows 10, xampp 7.2.2.

1. took backup of htdocs projects
2. uninstalled XAMPP 7.2.x
3. installed XAMPP 5.6.x
4. pasted backup projects to htdocs
5. got Apache port number issue, then change 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf
6. works fine !

Comment: I ended up using different OS, so I dont know if this will actally work in my case, I will accept it anyways as it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

### XAMPP MySQL is not running

Solution->
1.Open cmd and type 'services.msc'

2.Service panel will be opened within 5 seconds

3.Now search for anyother sql server which is still running

4.Select all the sql servers and stop them one by one service(There could be more than one)

5.Finally refresh your computer and start MySQL

6.Enjoy

Hope it will run successfully now :=)