# MySQL not starting - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am new to MySQL and I don't know why but MySQL does not start with XAMPP.
I thought that the 3306 port was blocked but I checked and nothing is running on that port.
If I go to XAMPP this is what is printed:

```
10:23:52  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
10:23:54  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:23:54  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:23:54  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:23:54  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:23:54  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:23:54  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:23:54  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:23:54  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

And this is the log of the error:

```
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-12-16 10:17:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 1699607; transaction id 3902
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-16 10:17:55 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that port 3306 is not used by other processes ?

Comment: Yes, it is the first thing that I did but that was not the problem. Nothing is running on that port

Comment: hmm, there must be something wrong since your MySQL log doesn't have any error. Maybe you can try to change the MySQL port. See if there's any luck

Comment: I don't know why but I made a copy of the database and I reinstalled XAMPP. The error is now gone and everything seems to be working perfectly. I still don't have any idea about the previous problem even because there were no error in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction

1.exit Xampp server

2.go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory

3.delete the ibdata1 file

4.restart xampp server

Comment: check this out, there are a lot solution will work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly