# Xampp MySQL Shutdown Again & Again

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, xampp

I have xampp installed with 10.4.24-MariaDB and PHP/8.1.4
MySQL works okay but sometimes it crashes. I follow the steps like putting the contents from backup folder replaing ibdata1 etc. Then it works but again crashes after few days.
Is there any way to keep it permanently fixed.
Mayble power failure of my PC is a reason??

```
16:19:48  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
16:19:48  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:19:48  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:19:48  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:19:48  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:19:48  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
16:19:48  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

my.ini

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# D:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is D:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
port=3306
socket="D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="D:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="D:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=10M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_flush_method=normal

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="D:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=64M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M
[mysqlhotcopy]
```

mysql_error.log

```
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=12734097
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database? Log sequence number in the ib_logfiles is 12734097, less than the log sequence number in the first system tablespace file header, 780719665.
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=102] with future log sequence number 771339310
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=890, page number=96] with future log sequence number 768500832
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=101] with future log sequence number 771314154
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=890, page number=95] with future log sequence number 768475084
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=39] with future log sequence number 770091619
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=234] with future log sequence number 773201335
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=38] with future log sequence number 773200702
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=233] with future log sequence number 773190957
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=232] with future log sequence number 773190957
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=231] with future log sequence number 773156971
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=411] log sequence number 779664998 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12734115.
2022-05-26 11:45:36 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-05-26 11:45:37 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=868, page number=1] log sequence number 718174603 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12734115.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 12734106; transaction id 114213
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220526 11:45:37
2022-05-26 11:45:37 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=12736905
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database? Log sequence number in the ib_logfiles is 12736905, less than the log sequence number in the first system tablespace file header, 780719665.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=102] with future log sequence number 771339310
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=890, page number=96] with future log sequence number 768500832
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=101] with future log sequence number 771314154
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=890, page number=95] with future log sequence number 768475084
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=39] with future log sequence number 770091619
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=234] with future log sequence number 773201335
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=38] with future log sequence number 773200702
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=233] with future log sequence number 773190957
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=232] with future log sequence number 773190957
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring a doublewrite copy of page [page id: space=892, page number=231] with future log sequence number 773156971
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=411] log sequence number 779664998 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12736923.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-05-26 11:52:52 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=868, page number=1] log sequence number 718174603 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 12736923.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 12736914; transaction id 114228
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-05-26 11:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220526 11:52:52
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-05-26 16:39:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Do you have log files you can post, without those it would be impossible for anyone to know what exactly is wrong. Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly Possible duplicate #2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/how-to-solve-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/61859561#61859561

Comment: @treckstar I know that these type of question is already present. but if you read my question carefully. I mentioned that i know how to fix it by those steps but again after 3 to 4 days it stops abruptly.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the last 100 lines of your Error Log?  SELECT @@log_error; to determine the name of your error log file.    If you have no filename displayed for log_error, within your my.ini disable the line with log_error by leading with a pound sign (#) and space character and stop/start MySQL when convenient so you have an error log.  View profile for contact info and get in touch, please.

Comment: So regardless if you can fix it or not, how would we even begin to debug this intermittent issues without having the log data?

Comment: When your instance has been running for 1 DAY - Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck It is not an instance it is just my pc with Windows 11, 8GB RAM. I have edited the question and updated the log. Kindly check and respond.
MySQL running fine for few days means that i was able to work it with daily for 3-4 days.

Comment: It appears someone deleted ibdata1 in reviewing the error log content of 5/26/2022.  I think you know how to reach me.