# MariaDB shutdown unexpectedly. mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed

Tags: windows, mariadb, xampp, mariadb-10.4

**mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files**

I am using xampp and it was working perfectly. Today when I started my Windows computer and tried to start the MariaDB Server from xampp control panel v3.3.0 the xampp showed the following error:

```
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:37:34 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

And when I checked the log file `mysql_error.log` the following error was displayed:

```
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M,     instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-09  9:37:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 35377535; transaction id 5422
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-09-09  9:37:33 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

The main problem is with Plugin 'Aria' which is not starting as shown in the first line of the log above

**mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files**

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete all files named as `aria_log.########` where ######## is any number from `xampp\mysql\data` folder.

I deleted the following file

```
aria_log.00000001
```

From `xampp\mysql\data` and the MySql server started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `aria_chk -r` as described in error logs?

this is example for recovering tables in mysql database:

`C:\xampp\mysql\bin>aria_chk -r ..\data\mysql\*.MAI`